# Ajax file upload doesn't work as normal

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload

I am using $.ajax to upload images to my server with sizes less than 200mb when I run this code on my computer using wampserver the code works fine and I upload images with appropriate sizes however when I run this website on online server like 000webhost and try to upload files with size more than about 160kb I get no response, is this normal?

My code

```
var formData = new FormData($('#uploadform')[0]);
    $.ajax({
      cache:false,
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'process.php',
      data: formData,
      beforeSend: function(){
        alert("Ready");
      },
      success: function(response){
    if(response=='Complete'){
        alert("Completed"); 
    }
},
contentType: false,
processData: false
}); 
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's a server limitation. I've never used this kind of host, but they must be very restrictive

Comment: Actually I am only using a small amount of my Disk usage.

Comment: Well, it can be a upload_max_size limitation. If you're using PHP. Try running this method on some file phpinfo(); It usually informs you about the server configuration and limitations.

Comment: I am using PHP, what do you mean by upload_max_size and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

on 000webhost server you can upload file with max-size 2 MB, I am using the same server and uploading files less than 2 MB works fine (with or without ajax).....share your code please

here do it like this

```
<script>
$().ready(function(){

    //
    var files;
    // Grab the files and set them to our variable
    $('form').on('submit', uploadFiles);
    $('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);

    function prepareUpload(e)
    {

        files = e.target.files;
        //alert(files);
    }


    function uploadFiles(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        //supports multiple file upload
        var data = new FormData();
        $.each(files, function(key, value)
        {
            data.append(key, value);
        });
        $.ajax({ 
            cache:false, 
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'process.php?files', 
            data: data, 
            beforeSend: function()
            { 
                alert("Ready");
             }, 
            success: function(response)
            { 
                if(response=='Complete')
                { 
                    alert("Completed"); 
                } 
            }, 
            contentType: 
            false, 
            processData: false 
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

the use $_GET['files] to grab the content in your process.php file

Comment: var formData = new FormData($('#uploadform')[0]);
    $.ajax({
      cache:false,
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'process.php',
      data: formData,
      beforeSend: function(){
        alert("Ready");
      },
      success: function(response){
    if(response=='Complete'){
        alert("Completed"); 
    }
},
contentType: false,
processData: false
}); 
}

Comment: I have tried many codes and tutorials in different forums even replacing $.ajax with XMLHttpRequest and all these ways work on my computer yet I get no response for large images -160kb on 000webhost

Comment: did you check phpinfo() for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size, you can override these with .htaccess.

php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M

add these lines to your .htaccess file, it might work, worked for me

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, could you explain more please.

Comment: to check info, just echo phpinfo() in a file in your server, for example index.php file.....and for .htaccess if you already have one, just add these two lines, if not, create one and add those two lines and upload to the server...

Comment: I checked phpinfo and it turns out that the max file upload is 2M, so the problem is not here.

Comment: okay....try this once, just to check whether the server is doing fine or not....just upload it and see it for yourself. Here is the link, 
http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: I don't think this code works, I downloaded it to localhost and somehow I get no response when pressing it "Submit Content", does it work for you?

Comment: yes, this works perfectly fine both on local and server.....what error did you get???

Comment: For the code you suggested when I press the "SubmitContent" button nothing happens, also I just tried to upload files(not images) like .txt file with my old code(above in my question) and I found that the code works fine and I could upload files of up to 1M, if higher than that I get a message saying "Request Entity Too Large", however if upload images of up to about 160kb I get no response not even a "Request Entity Too Large" message, is it a problem with images?

Comment: For the code you suggested when I press the "SubmitContent" button nothing happens, also I just tried to upload files(not images) like .txt file with my old code(above in my question) and I found that the code works fine and I could upload files of up to 1M, if higher than that I get a message saying "Request Entity Too Large", however if upload images of up to about 160kb I get no response not even a "Request Entity Too Large" message, is it a problem with images?

Comment: is this the issue only in the server??? I haven't seen this kind of problem......